# What does "INDEX = PK_DPAGODOCUMENTO" means in this sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm stuck with this query that was left by another programmer. I searched and searched, but I still have no clue. If someone could guide me, I would really appreciate it.

The query says

```
SELECT ... 
FROM dbo.DPAGODOCUMENTO AS T2 (INDEX=PK_DPAGODOCUMENTO) 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.MDOCUMENTO ... WHERE ...
```

where `PK_DPAGODOCUMENTO` is a `CONSTRAINT [PK_DPAGODOCUMENTO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` on the table `[DPAGODOCUMENTO]`.

What does `(INDEX=PK_DPAGODOCUMENTO)` really mean, and what does it do? We are using MSSQL 2005.

Comment: It's an index hint. Usually a bad idea (see here http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/10/index-hints-helpful-or-harmful/) . It looks like it's in a less common of `INDEX=`. Now tell us, what is the _actual problem_ you are trying to solve with this query? Are you just trying to understand it?

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer, i found something about hints before but in the documentation use the word "WITH ..." and this case does not and in fact shows an error for not use it; we are replacing a program that call this query inside a procedure, is an old program, if i comment the hint the query optimizer run for it self right? will i obtain the same result? again Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned below, removing the hint doesn't affect the result. It might change the performance (faster or slower or no change at all).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Table Level Query Hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) to override the default behaviour of SQL Server query optimizer and nudge it to use a specific index (PK_DPAGODOCUMENTO which is the Clustered Index in this case).

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer, i found something about hints before but in the documentation use the word "WITH ..." and this case does not and in fact shows an error for not use it; we are replacing a program that call this query inside a procedure, is an old program, if i comment the hint the query optimizer run for it self right? will i obtain the same result? again Thanks!

Comment: The output doesnt change on removing the query hints. Only the query plan changes

Comment: If you found the answer useful please mark it as an accepted answer and upvote so others users can know that the question has been answered.